# Authenticate using App Engine credentials to talk to an app on Google Cloud Endpoints with OpenAPI

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

If you use the [Google Auth Library for Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python) to authenticate an App Engine app to communicate with an app running on Compute Engine that uses the [Extensible Service Proxy (ESP)](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/about-cloud-endpoints) as part of [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) with OpenAPI, you get an error response:

```
{
  "code": 16,
  "message": "JWT validation failed: BAD_FORMAT",
  "details": [{
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
      "stackEntries": [],
      "detail": "auth"
  }]
}
```

The only [sample Cloud Endpoints code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/endpoints/getting-started/clients/service_to_service_gae_default/main.py) that I found doesn't use any library and instead builds the JSON Web Token (JWT) by hand and sets the proper HTTP header completely manually. Is there a way to do it with a standard library, so you get all the other benefits that come with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that `google.auth.app_engine.Credentials()` does not include the `aud` claim in the JWTs that it builds, while ESP requires it. (I wish I found the [Troubleshooting JWT Validation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-jwt-openapi) page earlier, it would have saved me hours I spent investigating this myself.)

Here is how to build credentials that ESP will accept:

```
import google.auth.app_engine
import google.auth.jwt
from google.appengine.api import app_identity

AUDIENCE = '...'

credentials = google.auth.jwt.Credentials(
    signer=google.auth.app_engine.Signer(),
    issuer=app_identity.get_service_account_name(),
    subject=app_identity.get_service_account_name(),
    audience=AUDIENCE)
```

where `AUDIENCE` must match the `x-google-audiences` value in your OpenAPI file **or** your Cloud Endponts service name (see the troubleshooting doc linked to above for details).

This code even works with `dev_appserver.py` and a service account as long as you pass the `--appidentity_private_key_path` and `--appidentity_email_address` flags. But you'll need to convert your service account's private key into the format that `dev_appserver.py` accepts, because it doesn't support either of the formats that the Google Cloud Console can give you. See [this bug comment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/574#issuecomment-186895605) for instructions.